# Which Windows API can get detailed info from one certificate in the Certificates(Local Computer)?

Tags: windows, certificate

I want to programmatically(c/c++) get the "Thumbprint" value in a specified certificate listed in the "Certificates(Local Computer)" mmc.

Is there any API that can help me achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Using CertOpenSystemStore, CertEnumCertificatesInStore and CertGetCertificateContextProperty API can solve the problem.